# O que faz popBackStack()?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Não consigo entender ou achar algum lugar que me faça entender o que faz o método `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();`

Nem mesmo lendo a documentação eu consegui entender, alguém poderia me explicar bem explicadinho e se possível fazendo analogias, entendo melhor com analogias.

Comment: Essa pergunta é boa, eu que uso não sei exatamente como funciona por trás dos panos, mas segue o princípio de pilha...

Quando vê faz transação envolvendo `Fragment`s e usa o `addToBackStack`, você está empilhando o estado anterior a alteração. Espero que alguém saiba responder corretamente.

Comment: @Walkim você ainda usa, eu nem chego a usar porque não consigo entender. Rsrsrs. Vamos esperar a resposta e ver no que vai dar. Preciso entender pois quase nem uso muito `Activitys` para navegação entre telas, uso mais `Fragments`.

Comment: Acreditam que eu fiz a mesma pergunta o SO em inglês e tomei -6 até o momento... ¬¬

Comment: Ja que ninguém se aventurou, vou dar uma olhada mais a fundo nesse conceito e tento responder a pergunta

Comment: Beleza @Wakim, se puder esclarecer acredito que irá tirar dúvida de muitas outras pessoas também.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vou arriscar minha resposta :)

Acredito que todos sabemos o que é `Fragment`. Vou partir deste princípio, caso alguém que venha a ler essa resposta não saiba recomendo a leitura desta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17483/qual-a-diferenca-entre-desenhar-na-activity-e-no-fragment).

O problema central é o `BackStack`, que é um item fundamental na utilização de Transações envolvendo `Fragments`.

É conhecido que toda transação que envolve adição e remoção de `Fragments` programaticamente na Activity você sempre verá um código dessa forma:

```
// Create new fragment and transaction
Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
transaction.commit();
```

O `BackStack` é uma pilha, como o próprio nome diz, que armazena estados da tela em relação as transações utilizando o `FragmentManager` em uma determinada `FragmentTransaction`. O `BackStack` permite, de forma transparente, a navegação entre os `Fragments` decorrente do empilhamento dos estados antes de cada `commit` da transação.

Todas as transações são assíncronas, isso é, elas são escalonadas para executar no próximo `Loop` da sua `Main Thread`. Caso queira executar de forma síncrona, existe o método [`FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#executePendingTransactions%28%29).

Se uma determinada transação, que envolve a remoção de um `Fragment`, for realizada e **não for adicionado uma entrada** no `BackStack`, não será possível restaurar o `Fragment` removido **utilizando os padrões de navegação**. Segundo a seção de  [Fragment Transaction](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions).

Abaixo segue uma explicação com imagens e ações, do funcionamento do `BackStack`.

---

### 1. Estado inicial da Activity com o Fragment1 embutido

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 2. Click no botão (Replace do Fragment1 pelo Fragment2)

Teria um código parecido com o primeiro que postei, para fazer o replace. E o resultado seria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando um `Fragment` é removido pelo método `remove` ou `replace` (implicitamente), sua `View` é destruída (o método `onDestroyView` é chamado) porém não ocorre nenhuma alteração em seu estado (salvo mudanças no ciclo de vida da `Activity` e que influencia o ciclo de vida do `Fragment`), logo todas as variáveis de instância do `Fragment` são mantidas.

### 3. Click no botão (Replace do Fragment 2 pelo Fragment3)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### 4. Navegação de volta pelo botão

Nesse caso, teriamos que usar um código desse tipo no `View.OnClickListener` do botão:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
// ou
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

O resultado se torna:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No `popBackStack` o FragmentManager se utiliza do registro da última transação realizada, para fazer a operação inversa. Removendo o `Fragment3` e adicionando de volta o `Fragment2`. Nesse momento apenas a `View` do `Fragment2` é recriada (método `onCreateView` é chamado).

### 5. Navegação de volta pelo item de back da Navigation Bar

O método `onBackPressed` da `Activity` é chamada. Se sua `Activity` herdar de `FragmentActivity` ou de `ActionBarActivity`, a chamada o `popBackStack` é feita pela `FragmentActivity`. Se não houver nada no `BackStack` ele irá finalizar a Activity normalmente. Nesse caso não se preocupe, a não ser que queria fazer algo personalizado caso contrário.

Se estiver utilizando a `Support Library v4`, de uma olhada no código fonte do [`FragmentActivity.onBackPressed()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.java#FragmentActivity.onBackPressed%28%29). Para versões do SDK 11+, a classe `Activity` ja tem esse comportamento já está incluso na [`Activity.onBackPressed()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onBackPressed%28%29)

O estado final de tela e do `BackStack` fica:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Espero que o conceito tenha ficado claro, ou pelo menos ajudado a começar a entender hehe.**

Acabei aprendendo bastante coisa ao escrever essa resposta, é claro que a maioria dos conceitos aqui eu retirei da página de documentação sobre `Fragments`. E as imagens feitas no Paint, não sou Designer então peço paciência.

Comment: primeiramente obrigado por responder e tentar ajudar a comunidade. Você disse: "No popBackStack o FragmentManager se utiliza do registro da última transação realizada, para fazer a operação inversa. Removendo o Fragment3 e adicionando de volta o Fragment2." No caso então se eu dou um `popBackStack()`, quando voltar para o fragment, ele voltará exatamente de como estava antes da transação ou ele será recarregado?

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi o item 5. Eu tenho uma classe que estende `FragmentActivity` ou `ActionBarActivity`, então quando eu apertar o botão voltar em qualquer fragment meu que esteja na tela, o método `onBackPressed()` da minha classe irá chamar o super da Activity que por sua vez chamará `popBackStack()`?

Comment: Em relação ao segundo comentário, é quase isso. Na lib de support quem chama o popBackStack são as duas subclasses. Já no SDK 11+, é a propria Activity quem chama. Até coloquei um link pro source code das classes. Vou responder o primeiro comentario.

Comment: Ok @Wakim.  Sem problemas, fico no aguardo.

Comment: @LucasSantos, fiz uns testes e minha suposição estava errada... Logo apaguei o comentário ja que estava errado. O que acontece ao dar `remove` num Fragment é: Sua View é destruída e não há salvamento de estado, porque o `Fragment` não é destruído, quando ocorre o `popBackStack`, aquela instância de `Fragment` é reutilizada, logo as variâveis de instância estão "intactas" (tirando problemas de memória, que foge o escopo da pergunta). Vou incluir isso na minha resposta.

Comment: Ok @Wakim. Entendi.

Comment: @Wakim, bela "arriscada". Esclarecedora, não encontrei nada muito bom sobre a Backstack de Fragment nem em inglês, somente na documentação oficial que não é tão esclarecedora assim, +1