# Qual a diferença entre desenhar na Activity e no fragment?

Tags: desempenho, android-layout, android-fragment

Depois da ultima atualização do SDK no Eclipse, ao criar um novo projeto, cria-se também um `fragment` junto a `activity_main`. Gostaria de saber o porquê de agora ser criado o `fragment`, já que antes abria direto a `activity_main`. Há alguma diferença na performance do projeto?
Obrigado

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Já que ninguém se aventurou, vou tentar ajudar com o que aprendi sobre `Fragments`.

Antes de entrar brevemente em detalhes, gostaria de esclarecer que a perda de performance (custo x benefício) é muito irrisória em relação a flexibilidade, reuso, evolução dos smartphones (processamento, armazenamento, RAM, etc...) e as facilidades que o `Fragment` traz.

### O que é um Fragment?

A grosso modo o `Fragment` é um "Pedaço Autônomo" de interface. Assim como a `Activity`, ele possui um [ciclo de vida](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle) e um tratamento de armazenamento de estado (provido pelo `FragmentManager`), que é iniciado no momento que o `Fragment` é atrelado a `Activity` (*Attached*), e não necessariamente está visível na tela (Ele precisa ser adicionado ao layout, *Added*).

O `Fragment` surgiu no Android 11 (Honeycomb), que surgiu para ser o **SO**<sup>1</sup> de alguns Tablets, e a atual configuração (`Activity`), não atendia e tornava o desenvolvimento de interfaces que aproveitassem o tamanho de tela disponível muito mais difíceis (imagina um aplicativo de smartphone esticado numa tela de tablet? é muito ruim, mas isso existe).

Logo, eles tiveram a idéia para desenvolver o `Fragment`, que torna a composição de telas dinâmicas (em que pedaços de tela variam, seja em relação a orientação da tela, tamanho, contexto do usuário, gosto) muito mais fácil.

O `Fragment` está disponível na biblioteca [Support v4](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html) do SDK, então você pode usar o `Fragment` até nas versões anteriores ao 11. O que não te impede de usar agora.

Essa imagem do site oficial do android ilustra muito bem esse conceito:

[image: Fragments em Tablet e Handset]

Nessa imagem temos 2 `Fragments` sendo apresentados de duas das milhares de maneiras possíveis. Mas o importante é que o mesmo aplicativo para tablet e smartphone, usam o mesmo código e com muito poucas modificações nesse caso, isso é o mais importante (reuso).

*No caso do handset, **eu** particularmente não gosto um pouco da solução dada nessa imagem. Eu prefiro substituir o `Fragment` A pelo B e colocar ela na [`BackStack`](http://curioustechizen.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/nested-fragments-and-back-stack.html), assim quando o usuário apertar o `Backspace`, o `Fragment` A irá voltar. Outra questão é que nesse caso, algumas coisas vão involver comunicação entre `Activities`, o que eu prefiro evitar. **É questão de gosto, cada um tem o seu :P***

### Como começar a usar?

Existem duas formas de se adicionar um `Fragment` em uma `Activity`.

Seja no XML do seu layout, eles serão instânciados, `Attached` e `Added` automaticamente quando o layout for inflado:

#### XML do layout no Tablet (fica em res/layout-large)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleReaderFragment"
        android:id="@+id/viewer"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

#### XML do layout do smartphone (fica em: res/layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment android:name="com.example.news.ArticleListFragment"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Nesse caso, o `XML` acima é apenas da `Activity` A, o da `Activity` B é análogo, porém com o outro `Fragment`.

Ou programaticamente:

```
ExampleFragment fragment = new ExampleFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragment().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Recomendo fortemente a leitura da documentação oficial sobre [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html), tem até um exemplo que você pode fazer para entender melhor, vale a pena.

#### Prós e Contras

**Activity**

- Prós

  - Simplicidade de construção.
  - Facilidade de gerência do ciclo de vida.
  - Facilidade na criação de navegação entre activities.
- Contras

  - Layout é muito rígido, dificuldade de migração para layouts "MultiPane".
  - Facilidade de tornar o código monolítico e de difícil manutenção (Callback Hell).

**Fragment**

- Prós

  - Altamente modularizável.
  - Facilidade de reuso.
  - Facilidade de construção de layouts dinâmicos.
  - É possível utilizá-lo como uma forma de salvar estados da `Activity`, persistindo mesmo durante mudanças de configuração (mudança de orientação por exemplo).
- Contras

  - Maior complexidade de gerenciamento (Gerenciar o ciclo de vida não é tão fácil dependendo de como o `Fragment` é usado).
  - Comunicação entre `Fragment`s não é trivial, precisa da intervenção da `Activity`.

Esses são alguns prós e contras de cada um, pode ser que pela minha visão do assunto não esteja tão neutro, se alguém quiser acrescentar algo, é bem vindo.

Não vou me extender muito senão vai ficar muito grande e ruim para ler, se alguém quiser complementar o texto, é muito bem vindo!

***Deixo uma recomendação, por experiência própria: Faça tudo usando `Fragment`s, nem que seja uma `Activity` com apenas um `Fragment`, porque quando for evoluir seu aplicativo, se torna muito mais fácil pra reaproveitar o que foi feito, além de ter a oportunidade de oferecer uma interface mais rica para Tablets, que é muito bem visto na hora de publicar seu aplicativo na Play Store.***

Comment: O ponto exatamente seria vantagens e desvantagens, em relação a activity... Tem como você citar algumas por favor? Apenas pra complementar..

Comment: Tudo bem, vou complementar em breve

Comment: @GH_, alterado!

Comment: Muito obrigado cara, clareou minha mente e ainda me deu dicas de como usar o fragment! Eternamente grato hahaha