# Uso de Fragments

Tags: android-fragment

Sou iniciante em android. Estou aprendendo usando as video aulas do professor Neri, porém nas video aulas dele (android 2.2) não usava fragments, mas nos meus projetos que estou criando ele sempre cria com fragment, tanto é que o layout eu desenho na fragment_main, mas não estou sabendo usar esse fragment corretamente. Alguém pode me indicar um artigo que explique essa parte do uso de fragments, pois várias vezes estou tendo problemas com isso fazendo que minha aplicação simplesmente feche.

Comment: De uma olhada nessa pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17483/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-desenhar-na-activity-e-no-fragment. Nela eu tento esclarecer alguns conceitos e o uso do `Fragment` em favor de usar apenas `Activitys` e também as vantagens e desvantagens de cada um. Acho que poder ser útil para você.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro ler a própria documentação do Android, lá está explicando tudo sobre Fragments.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html